# C++ function overload priority

Tags: c++, overloading

Why would the code give an output: `bool` ?
Is there any way I could make the `const char*` to match the `string` version?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void func(bool)
{
    std::cout << "bool" << std::endl;
}

void func(const std::string&)
{
    std::cout << "string" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    func("hello");
}
```

Comment: `func(std::string("hello"));`

Comment: Any alternative without explicit construct the `std::string`? I'd like the complier gives an ambiguous warning rather than matches the `bool` version.

Comment: Maybe there is a compiler option but it would be compiler dependent try -Wall on gcc

Comment: @prmottajr I tried `-Wall` on clang but no warning shows.

Comment: You don't get an ambiguous warning because the call is not ambiguous.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30991816

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because the compiler will prefer built-in conversions to user-defined conversions. The conversion from a pointer to a `bool` is built-in, so that overload is selected rather than constructing a `std::string`.

You could add an overload which takes a `const char*` and forwards it to the `std::string` version:

```
void func(const char* arg)
{
    func(std::string{arg});
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the operator `{}`?

Comment: That's [uniform initialization](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax). It's a C++11 feature.

Answer (score 6):

To answer the why:

Function matching is the process by which the compiler selects which function to call among an overload set.
Here, there are two viable candidates (the two functions you defined). To pick one, the compiler ranks the conversion they imply.

The first candidate `void func(bool)` implies an array-to-pointer conversion followed by a boolean conversion (from `const char[6]` to `const char*` to `bool`)
The second candidate implies a user-defined conversion (calling the `std::string` ctor taking a `const char*`)

The second conversion has lower ranking, so the first candidate is selected as the best match.

Comment: Thank you Angew ! So C++ Primer is sloppy with its terminology... (6.6.1)

Answer (score 2):

According to the standard [N4431](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4431.pdf) *§13.3.3.2/2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences [over.ics.rank] **(emphasis mine)**:*

> **When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences** (as
>   defined in 13.3.3.1) (2.1) — **a standard conversion sequence**
>   (13.3.3.1.1) **is a better conversion sequence than a user-defined
>   conversion sequence** or an ellipsis conversion sequence, and (2.2) — a
>   user-defined conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.2) is a better conversion
>   sequence than an ellipsis conversion sequence (13.3.3.1.3).

Consequently, because the `char const *` to `bool` is a standard implicit conversion compared to the implicit conversion to `std::string` which is a user-defined conversion is a better conversion and is preferred in overload resolution.

In order to force overload resolution to choose the `std::string` version:

```
func(std::string("hello"));
```

Comment: This looks like the only straight-up answer that explains how the language works without putting any blame on "the compiler".

Comment: @KerrekSB Isn't the language actually defined by what a conforming compiler does?

Comment: @Angew: That's an extremely perverted way of viewing the world, but I guess you could see it that way...

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't actually view the world that way (1.1/1 and 1.4/2 notwithstanding). It's just that I don't see that much of a distinction between saying "the language dictates this" and "the compiler does this." As long as the compiler is following the standard, I consider these two equivalent.

Comment: @Angew: Code makes sense even if you never compile it. You can talk about the expression `f(x)` without compiling code, and overload resolution is still relevant. Code and logic are more fundamental than the act of compilation. It seems like pointless noise and distraction to pollute a discussion of code with ancillary musings about compilation. Why not also discuss what the code would look like when printed in pink Comic Sans?